# Java - Escaping Characters

Tags: java, html

I am escaping a referer param to prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS). However something weird happens when it comes to the front end.

I can confirm that my code does escape it correctly. The following unit test passes:

```
@Test
public void testEscapeURLDefaultWithQuotesAndAlertQuery() {
    String urlPath = "/listDeals.do";
    String queryParams = "/h1=en&q=2ce12\"onmouseover=\"alert(1)\"style=\"position:absolute;width:100%;height%;top:0;left:0;\"2ce12";
    String result = TermsheetAction.escapeURL(urlPath, queryParams);
    assertNotNull(result);
    assertEquals("/listDeals.do/h1=en&q=2ce12&quot;onmouseover=&quot;alert(1)&quot;style=&quot;position:absolute;width:100%;height%;top:0;left:0;&quot;2ce12", result);
}
```

However in the browser the URL comes back something like this:

```
h1=en&q=2ce12"nmouseover="lert(1)"tyle="osition:absolute;width:100%;height%;top:0;left:0;"ce12
```

In summary it is escaped to:

```
/listDeals.do/h1=en&q=2ce12&quot;onmouseover=&quot;alert(1)&quot;style=&quot;position:absolute;width:100%;height%;top:0;left:0;&quot;2ce12", result
```

but the browser removes the first letter next to the quote.

Thanks!

Comment: Double-quotes in URL's should be URL-encoded as `%22`, not as `&quot;`. `&quot;` is HTML-encoding, not URL-encoding.

Comment: Could you post code for `TermsheetAction.escapeURL(urlPath, queryParams);`?

Comment: I might be on the wrong track then, I am trying to prevent XSS, so we set the referer URL and that could be intercepted with JS.

I then take that URL and html escape it to remove any HTML, if I were to URLEncode it the referer URL would not work.

It would replace the =, the & with other characters that the browser would not understand.

Am I correct in doing the HTML Escaping then?

Comment: [Solved]

Used URLEncoder to encode each param. Needed to split it into key values.